# Get the last en for last day of a month

Tags: vb.net

I have a date like 27-12-2010 ( day-month-year ) .I need the following value back.

31-12-2010 ( Last day of that month )

30-12-2010 ( For last day of that month )

Comment: If you accepted answers, people would be more likely to help.

Comment: How about going from the semi-imperative "I need value", to something like "How can this be done?" - or even some code, which shows you current approach and what your problem is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the last day of the the month specified, use this:

```
Dim original As DateTime = DateTime.Now ' The date you want to get the last day of the month for
Dim lastOfMonth As DateTime = original.Date.AddDays(-(original.Day - 1)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

A bit long winded, but it guarantees you won't somehow end up with the first of the following month or the second to last of the month.

Comment: This also takes into account leap years, it will show the last day of each month. +1

Comment: Yeah. All it does is get the first day of the current month, add a month (which always gives us the 1st of the next month) and subtract a day.

Comment: I had a situation where I needed to add 1 month to a date but make sure I always had the last day.  By default this was slowly drifting the day down to the lowest common denominator (28).  I just did the add 1 month then on the next line your code.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get the beginning day and last day of the current month:

```
Dim thisMonth As New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1)

'beginning day of the month
thisMonth.ToString("yyyy-MM-01")

'last day of the month
thisMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: I don't think that is a good approach (even though it might work), because you would always to avoid conversion and especially to string. It has a poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

The responses above dealt with the current date (Today) only.
Below is an equivalent way of obtaining the first and last dates of the month, for any given date.

Suppose myDate is a DateTime type variable which contains the date to operate with:

```
Dim firstOfMonth = New DateTime(myDate.Year, myDate.Month, 1)

Dim lastOfMonth = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, Date.DaysInMonth(myDate.Year, myDate.Month) - 1, firstOfMonth)
```